# Suggested way for ADF to trigger pipeline by SQL table change

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-data-factory

I have a tracking SQL table which has following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST_TABLE](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [value] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [status] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [source] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [timestamp] [datetime] NULL
)
```

My application code will automatically maintain the table by inserting record and updating the field `status`.

My target is to trigger an ADF pipeline based on the result of following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM [dbo].[TEST_TABLE] WHERE [status] = 'active'
```

If the result is >0, then trigger an ADF pipeline.

**Current status:**

My current work:

1. set up an Stored procedure SP_TEST to return 1 if condition is filled; otherwise 0
2. setup an pipeline like below:
   [image]

the result of SP is parsed and used for routing to trigger later stages (which will mark the SQL table status to 'inactive' to avoid duplicate processing)
3. associate the pipeline with a scheduling trigger every 5 minutes.

My current work is "working", in the sense that it can **detect for whether there is DB change** every 5 minutes and execute subsequent processing.

**Problem:**

However, the scheuling trigger may be too frequent and cost activity run unit on every execution, which could be costly. Is there any trigger like "SQL table change trigger"?

**what I have tried:**

- A quick google points me to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/197465/how-to-trigger-an-adf-based-on-any-data-changes-wi.html), but seems no answer yet.
- I am also aware of storage event trigger and custom events trigger. Unfortunately, we are not permitted to create other Azure resource. Only the existing ADF and SQL server is provided to us.

Appreciate any insights/directions in advance.

Comment: Long-polling the database is the only solution currently available. If you are worried about excessive pipeline runs, you could move the polling check to a Logic App and have it execute the pipeline only when a new row is discovered. Of course, that would require the ability to create a new Azure resource.

Comment: Thanks @JoelCochran for your advice, which make sense to me too. I will just hang around a while longer to see if anyone else have some new input before I go back to my azure admin with your insight :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling using ADF can be expensive, we want to avoid that. Instead have the polling take place within an Azure Logic App, it's much cheaper. Here are the steps to listen to a SQL Server DB (Azure included) then trigger an ADF pipeline if a table change is found.

[image: Azure Logic App Design]

Here is the pricing for Azure Logic App:

[image: Azure Logic App Pricing]

I believe this means that every trigger is using a standard connector, so it will be  12.5 cents (USD) per 1000 firings of the app, and 2.5 cents (USD) per 1000 actions triggered.

For ADF it is $1 (USD) per 1000 activities, so it's much more expensive for ADF

Please let me know if you have any issues at all!

Comment: Thanks @TrentTamura for the solution first :) Currently I am not allowed to create other Azure resources. Will communicate to my Azure admin if there is no other option :)

Comment: :) just tell him it can save X amount of dollars per month.

Comment: Thanks @TrentTamura. Our Azure admin takes your advice and we are going to build Azure logic app for this. Many thanks for your help :D