# Transfer huge data from maria db to ssms when their is data change in mariadb

Tags: mariadb, azure-data-factory

I did tried using schedular for Databricks notebook but it is creating unnecessary of loading data. The data in mariadb changes randomly it is not fixed , if I try pipeline I cant call a trigger for change in data and transfer of data from one Database to another.

Please help me with any pipeline ideas , azure datafactory ideas or python codes as well so that I can transfer tables when their are changes in Mariadb

Answer (score 0):

One way to trigger pipeline is to use **event-based trigger**.

Creating event-based trigger in Azure Data Factory. Create trigger and select Type as Custom events.
[image]

Refer - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6063/create-event-based-trigger-in-azure-data-factory/

Second way is to use **logic app**. This is the best approach for your query.

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68384254) by [Trent Tamura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7410998/trent-tamura)